# How to filter formatted input in C?

Tags: c, string, formatting

I have a console input like this:

> aaaabbbbccccdddd 2 3 x 100 "value : %s" "xyz"

where

- `argv[1]=aaaabbbbccccdddd`
- `argv[2]=2`
  .
  .
  .
- `argv[6]="value : %s"`
- and `argv[7]=\"xyz\"`

My question is that how can I print safely the `argv[6]` and `argv[7]`, and by safely I mean that for regular string input which is not containing string formatting elements like `\`, `"`, `%s` the program should return an error.

Comment: Is your concern that `printf(argv[6])` will crash, because there's a format specifier asking for a string, but there isn't any additional string argument? Avoid user input as format strings and `printf("%s", argv[6])` and you should be fine for all arguments. (Or use `puts(argv[6])`, which print the string and a newline or `fputs(stdout, argv[6])`, which does the same without the newline.)

Comment: The quotation marks around `argv[7]` will usually be treated by the shell. Your program receives the processed string and you cannot tell whether the argument was `"xyz"` or just `xyz`.